# Recommendation for hardware to function as intercepting proxy

Tags: server

I am looking to get some hardware that I can setup as an intercepting proxy, to analyze network traffic.

The traffic would flow between a single PC and the internet and the total amount of traffic would be quite small (less than 4GB/day).

Since this would be a proxy it does not need to have a screen or a keyboard.

Here are some features for the hardware:

- Cost less than $300.
- Comes with software to log / trace connections (or ability to install e.g. Wireshark).
- Ability to export the trace files when needed.
- [Prefer but not a must] Able to function as a WiFi router.